# is there a way to use this ||(or) in this tuple array. then the arrays index with a map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples

```
let pokeArray = {
  pokemon: [
    {
      name: "Flabébé"  || "Flabebe",
      type: ["fairy"],
      imageData: "Not In Use",
      anchor: "Not In Use",
    },
]}


const pokeName = pokeArray.pokemon.map((x)=>x.name.toLowerCase())
let myPokemon = "Flabebe"
let inputMyPokemon = pokeName.indexOf(myPokemon.toLowerCase())
```

so this is the section of code im trying to get working "name: "Flabébé"  || "Flabebe","
i want it to be easy for the user to type in the name without accents and get the same result

i could duplicate the array entry with the 2nd spelling, but i would rather use an or comparator in the array if possible

Comment: Normalize the user's input, then use the normalized form for the `name` property

Answer (score -1):

A better way to compare words, regardless of their accents and capitalization:

```js
function areEquivalent(w1, w2) {
  return w1.localeCompare(w2, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0
}
areEquivalent("Flabébé", "flabebe") // true
```

---

Or as you are doing it:

```js
let pokeArray = {
  pokemon: [
    {
      name: ["Flabébé", "Flabebe"], // <- Use an array
      type: ["fairy"],
      imageData: "Not In Use",
      anchor: "Not In Use",
    },
]}

const pokeName = pokeArray.pokemon[0].name.map((x)=>x.toLowerCase())
let myPokemon = "Flabebe"
let inputMyPokemon = pokeName.indexOf(myPokemon.toLowerCase())
```

---

Comment: app.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: x.name.toLowerCase is not a function

tried this, the code isnt happy with this name being a tuple and no other name entry being a tuple

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working

Comment: app.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: pokeArray.pokemon[0].name.map is not a function

Comment: ok i guess it kinda works if i put EVERY name in an array, that feels a bit tacky, but i guess it works. it broke other things tho, so need to figure that out lol

Comment: o i see what it broke, whne i do it that way it returns -1 when i get indexOf() the game